# Configuring Managed APP to Use already configured IDP on Salesforce

Tags: salesforce, idp

We are trying to setup a managed app on Salesforce. Salesforce already uses 3rdParty(TP) as IDP. Now when user tries to login into the managed app it's redirected to salesforce, which redirects to IDP page for the keying in the creds. Once the creds are validated by IDP, it redirects to salesforce dashboard/landing page, instead of the managed app.

Configuration on the Managed App is something like the below

```html
{
  "client_id": "..................",
  "authority": "https://xxxxxx.my.salesforce.com/",
  "tenant": "services",
  "redirect_uri": "https://......./.../authenticate/get", //managed app redirect url
  "web_client_id": ".........",
  "token_uri": "token",
  "resource": "https://xxxxxxxx.my.salesforce.com/services/auth/test/XYZ",
  "web_api": true,
  "on_success_url": "/redirect_login",
  "authority_uri": "/auth/oauth/XYZ",
  "client_secret": ".......................................",
  "scope": "openid"
}
```

On Salesforce its setup as per the IDP configuring guidelines.

I've 2 questions:

1. Firstly, is it possible to setup a managed app with above flow ?
2. If yes, what needs to changed to redirect the login response to the managed app screen than stop at the salesforce dashboard.

- We tried changing the redirect URI on salesforce, but as the IDP redirect uri needs to match with the salesforce, that doesn't work at all.
- If we use the IDP directly on the managed app as OAUTH2/OpenIDConnect, it works, but it doesn't give me the salesforce session, instead give me IDP JWT which is of no use. I need the salesforce auth token for syncing the updates from managed app to salesforce.